Dynamic Log level by monitoring configuration file with filesystem watcher is resulting in system.IO exception
I want to reload my log level by changing configuration file without application restart. I added filesystem watcher to monitor changes in config
static void OnConfigFileChanged()
{
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");

    int newLogLevel = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogLevel"].ToString());

    if (SystemParamsDto.LogLevel != newLogLevel)
    {
        SystemParamsDto.LogLevel = newLogLevel;
        LogWriter.applicationLogLevel = (LoggingLevel)SystemParamsDto.LogLevel;
        LogWriter.WriteLog(new LogDto() { FunctionName = "OnConfigFileChanged", LogStringLevel = LoggingLevel.Exceptional, AdditionalInfo = $"LogLevel updated to {LogWriter.applicationLogLevel}", Message = "LogLevel_change" });
    }
}

This logs are visible on config change but after that it results in application crash with a System.IO.Exception:

Application: xxx.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.IOException
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, Int32, Boolean, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions, System.String, Boolean)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileShare)
at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.StaticOpenStreamForRead(System.String)
at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigHost.OpenStreamForRead(System.String, Boolean)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.RefreshFactoryRecord(System.String)
Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.hlClearResultRecursive(System.String, Boolean)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.hlClearResultRecursive(System.String, Boolean)
at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.ClearResult(System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord, System.String, Boolean)
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.RefreshConfig(System.String)
at Beanbag.DataProcessor.Controller.DataProcessorC. ()
at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.OnChanged(System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)
at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.CompletionStatusChanged(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)

This crashes only when application is simultaneously trying to write some logs. When there is no load function is working fine.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You are using a wrong approach. Please look into options pattern and specifically on how to use IOptionsMonitor
